# Как добавить на сайт коменты?

Tags: html, javascript

На сайт хочу добавить коменты к фоткам, дайте скрипт!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть один обалденный простейший способ, сходить на фейсбук, или вконтакте если хотите, взять у них код, вставить и забыть. И вам польза и регистрироваться большей части народа не потребуется.

Answer (score 2):

Есть простой способ - использовать сайты типа http://disqus.com/. Для того, что бы получить все и сразу, нужно добавить просто [скрипт](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/)
Из плюсов - можно будет рулить комментариями, присекать спам, пользователи не должны будут регистрироваться - просто используют свой твиттер/фесбук/гугл аккаунт.

Answer (score 0):

На каком движке Ваш сайт?

Только с JavaScript тут не обойтись - нужно знание PHP.
Предлагаю Вам, как вариант вставить плагин комментирования от ФэйсБука или Вконтакте.

Answer (score 0):

Plain html. То есть, рядом с каждой фоткой пишите нужный вам текст.

Comment: а лучше прямо на фотографиях в paint подписи сделать

Answer (score 0):

В index.html

```
<center><img src="3195.gif"></center><br><br>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="270" src="comm.html" width="100%"></iframe><br>
<center>Добавить комментарий:<br>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="161" src="comm.php" width="187"></iframe>
</center><br><br><br>
<center><a href="index.html">На главную</a></center>
<body alink="black" link="black" vlink="black">
```

В comm.php

```
<html>
<title>Заголовок</title>
<form action=enter.php method=POST>
    <form action="enter.php" method="post">
        Ваше имя:<br>
            <input name="name" size="" value="">
                <br>Ваш e-mail:<br>
                    <input name="mail" size="" value="">
                        <br>Комментарий:<br>
                             <input name="comm" size="" value="">
                                 <br>
```

В enter.php

```
<?php
$name = $POST[name];
$mail = $POST[mail];
$comm = $_POST[comm];
$all  = "Имя: $name Mail: $mail <br> Комментарий: <br>$comm <br><br>";
$file = fopen("comm.html", "a");
fputs($file, $all);
fclose($file);
?>

<center>Ваш комментарий успешно добавлен!<br>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url:/index.html" />
```